# How to test a single failing test when building perl

Tags: perl, testing

This issue usually is encountered when trying to run `make test` and sees one test fails. The README describes one can run each test individually, didn't clearly specifies how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make test` uses the script called `TEST` in the test directory (`t`). To replicate `make test` of a single file, one would use this script as follows:

```
[.../perl/t]$ ./perl -I../lib TEST op/array.t
t/op/array ... ok
All tests successful.
Elapsed: 0 sec
u=0.01  s=0.00  cu=0.03  cs=0.02  scripts=1  tests=194
```

If you want to see the raw output of the test script, you can run `perl` as follows:

```
[.../perl/t]$ ./perl -I../lib op/array.t
1..194
ok 1
ok 2
ok 3
...
ok 192 - holes passed to sub do not lose their position (multideref, mg)
ok 193 - holes passed to sub do not lose their position (aelem)
ok 194 - holes passed to sub do not lose their position (aelem, mg)
```

The above information and more is found in [perlhack](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlhack.html).

> This document explains how Perl development works. It includes details about the Perl 5 Porters email list, the Perl repository, the Perlbug bug tracker, patch guidelines, and commentary on Perl development philosophy.

---

Note that you need to run `make test_prep` before the above commands work. (If you've run `make test`, you've effectively run `make test_prep` already.)

Answer (score 1):

Run `./perl harness ../foo/boo.t` in the `t` directory, with `foo/boo` the name of the failing test.

Comment: If the script load any modules, you'll need `-I../lib`.

Answer (score 1):

To run a single test script, use `perl`, or better, `prove`.  Assuming you are in the module's base directory:

```
prove -lv t/some-test-script.t
```

This will run the test script against the libraries in `./lib`, with fallback to the libraries available to your install of Perl.

If you want to use the build libraries built by `make`, then this:

```
prove -bv t/some-test-script.t
```

Now the test script will be run against the libraries in `./blib`, falling back to libraries installed for your Perl.

The test scripts are typically just Perl scripts that live in a `t/` or `xt/` or some similar path within the distribution's directory structure. So you can also run them just with Perl:

```
perl -Iblib t/some-test-script.t
```

But prove produces nicer test summary information and color coding.

That is about as granular as you can get unless tests are written to allow for targeting specific segments within a test script. If you need to target a specific test within a test script you'll usually have to dig into the test code itself.

Comment: The question is about building Perl, not Perl modules.

Comment: Great answer, but not an answer to the question asked (which is about testing `perl` itself). Why don't you ask the question this answers, and post your answer there? (`prove` can be used to test `perl`, but the syntax is as follows (from the `t` dir): `./perl -I../lib ../utils/prove op/array.t`)